# Nobel prize winner database

Tags: mysql

I have the Nobel prize winners database since the year it was first awarded. The source of the data is : http://www.aggdata.com/awards/nobel_prize_winners

It has one single table, so there is no foreign key nor any ER.

The table has following 12 columns: Id, Year, Category, Name, Birthdate, Birth Place, County, Residence, Role/Affiliate, Field/Language, Prize Name, Motivation.

Obviously there are multiple winners for categories such as physics, medicine etc.

I have been trying to see the number of Nobel prize winners per category per decade using query. I want my result table to look like:

```
______________________________________________
1960-1969 Peace 9 winners
1960-1969 Physics 19 winners
..............................................
1970-1979 Peace 6 winners
1960-1969 Physics 12 winners
..............................................
______________________________________________
```

Can this be possible through a query in MySQL?

Much appreciate your attention. Thank you all/

Comment: It can no doubt be done.  Can you edit your question and provide a layout of the table(s) you are using?

Comment: Is the "Nobel prize winners database" a MySQL database? Do the existing tables contain the necessary info? If you answer "yes" to both of these questions then it is possible.

Comment: The database I took is from : http://www.aggdata.com/awards/nobel_prize_winners. It has the following fields: Year
Category
Name
Birthdate
Birth Location
Birth Country
Residence
Role/Affiliation
Field/Language
Prize Name
Motivation

Comment: You should first do a proper model of the database. Read up a little bit on ER-modeling and how to build relational databases. What you're looking for is a database design with tables for categories, winners and possibly more. The you connect these tables with "foreign keys". Then you simply send clever queries to the database that will serve you up with a prsentation of the data you'r asking for

Comment: @user3344580: please edit your question to include the additional information (it's easier to read it in one place than across various comments). Ideally you can then delete it from comments, to keep the question tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more SQL way to do this:

```
select concat(floor(npw.year / 10)*10, '-', floor(npw.year / 10)*10+9) as decade,
       npw.category,
       count(*) as winners
from NobelPriceWinners npw              
group by floor(npw.year / 10), npw.category
order by decade, category;
```

This produces three columns as:

```
Decade    Category    Winners
1960-1969 Peace          9
1960-1969 Physics       19
. . .
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks, but somehow is got the following result from the query:    <br/>                                                                             decade category winners
190-199 chemistry 56
191-200 chemistry 40
192-201 chemistry 54
193-202 chemistry 56
194-203 chemistry 43
195-204 chemistry 72
196-205 chemistry 79
197-206 chemistry 104
198-207 chemistry 97
199-208 chemistry 104
200-209 chemistry 123
201-210 chemistry 11

Comment: That should be `*10` in the `select`.

Comment: Yes, I got the desired groups for the decades (i.e. 1900-1910, 1911-1920, and so on). But the any clue about why' Chemistry' is in every row. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas:

Assuming you want to represent the decade as xxx0-xxx9, and assuming the award_date is DATE datatype, you can use an expression to get first three characters of year:

```
SUBSTR(DATE_FORMAT(t.award_date,'%Y'),1,3)
```

A query something like this may get you started.

```
SELECT CONCAT(s.ccy,'0-',s.ccy,'9') AS decade
     , s.category 
     , CONCAT(s.count_winners,' winners') AS winners
  FROM ( 
         SELECT SUBSTR(DATE_FORMAT(t.award_date,'%Y'),1,3) AS ccy
              , t.category
              , COUNT(1) AS count_winners
           FROM mytable t
          WHERE t.award = 'winner'
          GROUP
             BY SUBSTR(DATE_FORMAT(t.award_date,'%Y'),1,3)
              , t.category
       ) s
```

The inline view aliased as `s` does the heavy lifting to get the result, the outer query does some formatting.

Note that this query does not return any "zero" counts.

If you also need to include "zero" counts, for all categories for all decades, that could be done as well, by introducing a row sources for "all category" and "all decades", and then doing a cross join between those and a left join to the inline view aliased as `s`.

The query above does not return include "0" count